# Is it possible to use tabular integration for this integral:

Tags: integration

$$\int x\ln x \ dx$$ 
If so,  which is $u$ and which is $v'$?

$u'$ for $u = \ln x$ never goes to zero, and setting $v' = \ln x$ just makes it more complicated.

Comment: The way to go is indeed $v'=x$, $u=\ln x$. I don't really understand the objections you are making, but they seem related to some context which is absent from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [tabular integration](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04141), I presume that you mean "integration by parts, organized in a table."  Whenever it is possible to integrate by parts, it is possible to organize that process in a table.  So, the answer to your question is "Yes."

That being said, here is how the integration by parts works out:  by the usual abuse of notation, let $u = \log(x)$ so that $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x$, and take $\mathrm{d}v = x\, \mathrm{dx}$ so that $v = \frac{1}{2}x^2$.  Then
\begin{align}
\int x \log(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&= \int u\,\mathrm{d}v \\
&= uv - \int v\, \mathrm du \\
&= \log(x)\cdot \frac{1}{2} x^2 - \int \frac{1}{2}x^2 \cdot \frac{1}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2} x^2 \log(x) - \frac{1}{2}\int x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{2} x^2 \log(x) - \frac{1}{4}x^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! I think that I just did the $\int v'$ wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should. The right substitution in this case should be $u=\ln x$ and $dv=x\, dx$.$$\begin{align*}\int x\ln x\, dx & =\frac {x^2\ln x}2-\frac 12\int x\, dx=\tfrac 12 x^2\ln x-\tfrac 14x^2\end{align*}$$The tabular method should be obvious from here.